# Video not display in proper width in ipad and iphone (safari)

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, video

In my application, `video not display on iPad and iPhone.`

Actually video code added in `mceEditor` from back-end and display it from front-end. I added below video code

```
<object width="640" height="360" data="https://youtube.com/v/s8kmoiOqVtI" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="src" value="https://youtube.com/v/s8kmoiOqVtI" />
</object>

<iframe src="https://youtube.com/v/s8kmoiOqVtI"></iframe>
```

I tried both above video code but using `object` tag its width display too small. Not display proper width on iPad and iPhone but video display.

`iFrame ->` Display width proper but not display video on iPad and iPhone devices

What i have to do video display proper width on devices.

I tried lots but not solved it then come here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use media query for it

For iphone put

```
media@(max-width:480px){
   Your css style for iframe according to you
}
```

For ipad put

```
media@(max-width:768px){
   Your css style for iframe according to you
}
```